# How to automatically close the google ads in the video player?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML5 video player for playing video from some videohostings. But before video can be played, there is advertising that can be closed. Video is encoded on another server, I just insert link to js script in the page.

Comment: Sounds like you are hotlinking some provider's videos and complaining that they put ads on their own videos. You also provide no code to look at...

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, script source http://goo.gl/xJpV37

Answer (score 1):

Try `adblocker` plugin in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Adblocker extension for Chrome shoudl help you. You can install this extension in Mozilla too.